# How to animate preferredContentSize when using UIPopoverPresentationController?

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewanimation

I am able to successfully change the frame of a popover I present by simply setting `preferredContentSize`. I would now like to animate the change in the content size but I haven't been successful. It just instantly updates, in fact the delay I have set isn't even respected. How could one animate the change in content size?

```
//In viewDidAppear:
UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 3, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400)
}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem, then figured out a way to make it work. The animation delay just isn't working here, so set that to 0 and do a different type of delay before doing the animation. I use a function I found here on SO:

```
func delay(delay: Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Just put that at the top of any swift file, outside of the class definition.

Then change your code to look like this:

```
delay(3, { () -> () in
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400)
        }, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: Awesome! I also noticed it doesn't like a content size of 0, 0 - it seems to set it to a default size instead. I want to animate it from 0, 0 to 320, 400. Do you know how that can be overridden?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. But it might be happy starting with a 1x1 size.

Comment: The lowest amount I could get it at was 60x60, which produces an undesirable effect starting at that size and animating out. Wonder if there's some other way to go about this.

Comment: I'd probably also animate the alpha. Start at 60x60 and an alpha of 0. My guess is that would look pretty good.

Comment: The popover has a default appearance, I don't believe you can completely hide the popover. I could animate the alpha of the view inside the popover but that wouldn't look right.