# UIPopoverPresentationController animate preferredContentSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopover

I am using `UIPopoverPresentationController` to present my tableView controller as PopOver. I am able to change its preferredContentSize to tableView contentSize as follows,

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewDidAppear: animated];
     self.preferredContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;
}
```

Here the problem is the contentSize is getting changed immediately which is not looking good. I tried animating it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860816/how-to-animate-preferredcontentsize-when-using-uipopoverpresentationcontroller) but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I tried changing the contentSize in `viewWillAppear` but it doesn't work and **I am using Objective C not Swift**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewDidAppear: animated];

     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         self.preferredContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;
     });
}
```